# Is it possible to estimate the interaction variance in a nested experimental design?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, random-effects-model

I have a partially nested study design where I want to estimate variance components for both the crossed and nested factors and their interactions. Is it possible to estimate the variance of an interaction variable if one of the variables is nested?

For example, say I have 20 `farm`s each with 10 `field`s that randomly receive 1 of 20 types of `fertilizer` across two different `season`s. The outcome measure is a measure of crop `yield`. Thus, `field` is nested within `farm`, and `farm`, `field`, and `season` are crossed with `fertilizer`. It's certainly possible to get all of the crossed main effects and interaction variances depending on what theoretical rationale there was for developing the model. However, would it be possible to estimate both the `farm` main effect variance and the `farm:field` interaction variance? Or is the interaction variance in a nested design confounded with the main effect variance? If so, is there any way to meaningfully parse the two? (`R` lets one run both in the same model, but I am not sure it is meaningful).

Here's a play example in `R`:

```r
library(lme4)

set.seed(1999)

df <- data.frame(
  yield = runif(n = 1000, 4, 100),
  farm = rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = 20, 50),
  field = rep(paste0(1:10), each = 2, 50),
  season = as.factor(rep(c("wet", "dry"), 500)
  fertilizer = as.factor(rep(sample(1:20), 200)) 
)

df$field <- paste0(df$field,"_", df$farm)

fit <- lme4::lmer(yield ~ 1 +
              (1|farm) +
              (1|field) +
              (1|fertilizer) +
              (1|season) +
              (1|season:field) +
              (1|farm:fertilizer) +
              (1|field:fertilizer) +
              (1|farm:field) # nested
              ,
            data = df,
            control = lmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa')
)

lme4::VarCorr(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible in principle. To see how, consider a much simpler example where you have just farms and fields in farms, with replicate observations on each field.

You can estimate a residual variance from the squared differences between replicates on the same field.  The squared difference between observations on the same farm but different fields will tend to be larger than the residual variance but smaller than the squared difference between observations on different farms. That gives you two variance components: one for farms and one for fields within farms.

In your design you don't have any pure replicates, but the same sort of estimation conceptually applies to residuals after subtracting off the fixed effects.  If within-field differences in residuals are smaller than within-farm differences and smaller in turn than between-farm differences you have evidence for both field and farm random effects.

Whether you can estimate a particular set of fixed effects and variance components is a more complicated question, but given that it's possible in principle you might just trust `lme4` to have got that right.